# Are all convex hulls polytopes too?

Tags: geometric-topology, polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

A convex hull of a set $X$ of points is defined as:

> the smallest convex set that contains $X$.

Does this definition imply that all convex hulls of a convex set are in fact, polytopes of their respective dimensions?

Comment: Did you try a 2d example?

Comment: The convex hull of a convex set is the set itself !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question seems to me to indicate several confusions.

Here are some facts you should understand. They follow from the definition of "convex hull".

- A set has just one convex hull, so you needn't ask about "all convex
  hulls".
- If a set is convex then it is its convex hull (as @YvesDaoust
  comments).
- The convex hull of a finite set will be a polytope. Its dimension may be lower than the dimension of the containing space - for an example think about the convex hull of two points in the plane (or even the convex hull of one point on the line).
- Any polytope is the convex hull of the (finite) set of its vertices.
- The convex hull of (the circumference of) a circle in the plane is
  the circle together with its interior. Clearly that's not a polytope.

Comment: Great! You explained it better than most of the sources I'm reading off. Just to clarify, in the third point, why have you mentioned "perhaps of dimension lower than containing space"? Thanks!

Comment: @UnimpressedLemur You're welcome. See my edit.

Comment: Ohh I get it now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @EthanBolker By the fourth fact do you mean to imply that every polytope is a convex polytope?

Comment: @toric_actions Whether or not every polytope is convex depends on the definition of "polytope". Some definitions allow for nonconvexity. Then the assertion is false.  If a polytope is an intersection of half spaces then the assertion is true.